# Is there a Winforms control to manage Application Settings?

Tags: .net, winforms, configuration

Is there a way to display a dialogue to edit application settings for the end user at run time?  The same dialogue that is shown at design time in Visual Studio would work nicely...  For example the connection string property dialogue is helpful.

Or do I need to build a custom form to edit the settings?  I would have expected a more convenient method or some helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a control already made for that in the default toolbox. Its called PropertyGrid. I believe that this is exactly what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much - I suspected there was something.  I was using the wrong terminology with google... *faceplant

Comment: Coming from the web end of things I wouldn't have thought to search 'property' but on configuration/settings/etc